Strongest Result on Existence of Minimal Sufficient Statistic
Let $X$ be a random variable taking values in a measurable space $(\mathcal{X}, F_{\mathcal{X}})$ whose distribution $P_{\theta}$ is chosen from a parametric family of probability measures $\mathcal{P} = \{ P_{ \theta } \}_{\theta \in \Theta}$ on $\mathcal{X}$. A sufficient statitic is a measurable function $T$ defined on $\mathcal{X}$ such that the regular conditional probability $P_{X \mid T(X)}$ (let us suppose that it exists) does not depend on the choice of $\theta$. A sufficient statistic $T$ is said to be minimal sufficient if, for any other sufficient statistic $S$, there is a measurable function $\psi$ such that $T(X) = \psi(S(X))$ almost surely with respect to any $P \in \mathcal{P}$.
Up to now, what is the statement of the strongest result for the existence of minimal sufficient statistic in the sense that the result posts minimum restrictions on spaces $\mathcal{X}$ and $\Theta$ such that, for all "not too terribly organized" (for instance, with densities being measurable in product spaces) parametric family $\mathcal{P}$, a minimal sufficient statistic always exists ? No need to concern on how to compute it. Existence is all I need.
